# Django.Файл views.py. Интерпретатор ругается относительно отступов на строке 10.Можете проверить и обьяснить где я допустил оплошность

Tags: python, django

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    appid = '' # Я здесь ввожу свой apikey 
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=' + appid

    city = 'London'
    res = requests.get(url.format(city))
    print(res.text)

    return render(request, 'testproject/index.html')
```

Comment: отредактируйте код, ничего не понятно

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, приводите текст ошибки. В данном случае у вас проблема в том, что где-то отступы сделаны табами, где-то пробелами. Это видно если посмотреть исходник вопроса в первой редакции: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/71fe0aff-78b7-417a-9b50-1cfa92d1827c/view-source

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка неправильного использования отступов вызвана тем, что вы используете табы и пробелы одновременно (на одном уровне вложенности). Чтобы впредь подобные ошибки было проще замечать, вы можете покопаться в настройках своего текстового редактора и включить отображение невидимых символов. Указал ниже, на каких строках у вас используются табы, а на каких - пробелы. Исправьте, и код будет работать.

```py
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    appid = '' # Я здесь ввожу свой apikey  # tab
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=' + appid # tab

    city = 'London' # space
    res = requests.get(url.format(city)) # space
    print(res.text) # space

    return render(request, 'testproject/index.html') # tab
```

Answer (score 0):

может стоит поставить правильные отступы, например так:

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    appid = '' # Я здесь ввожу свой apikey 
    url = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid=' + appid

    city = 'London'
    res = requests.get(url.format(city))
    print(res.text)

    return render(request, 'testproject/index.html')
```